# How do I take UNIQUE random choice from two lists

Tags: python, random

I have two lists that defines a card

```
values  =  ['A', 'K', 'Q', 'J', '10', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4', '3', '2']
marks   =  ['spade', 'hearts', 'diamond', 'club']
```

I want to have 12 **unique** cards, so my **output** should look like

```
('9', 'diamond')
('K', 'hearts')
('Q', 'hearts')
('7', 'spade')
('A', 'diamond')
('3', 'diamond')
('Q', 'diamond')
('3', 'hearts')
('7', 'hearts')
('2', 'diamond')
('2', 'hearts')
('5', 'spade')
```

I have used random choice to get this far, my code is here

```
count = 0
while count != 12:
    value = random.choice(values)
    mark = random.choice(marks)
    card = Card(value, mark) 
    # I have a class named Card, generate() returns a tuple of mark and value for card
    print(card.generate())
    count += 1
```

But it does not provide me unique values. Please let me know or through me a resource to learn how to get unique value by random choice from two lists.

Comment: Use `random.shuffle`, like you would with a real stack of cards (Or `random.sample` if you need just a few)

Comment: @tobias_k: For that to do the job, you'd need to make a deck to be shuffled; just shuffling the `values` and `marks` separately couldn't generate the example output.

Comment: Random.shuffle does not pick and combine elements from two separate lists.
Is there anyway I can bypass this ? @tobias_k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, combine the `marks` and `values` to actual cards using `itertools.product`, then just `random.shuffle` the stack of cards and `pop` cards into the player's hand, like you would in real life.

```
import itertools, random
cards = list(itertools.product(values, marks))
random.shuffle(cards)
hand = [cards.pop() for _ in range(12)]
```

At the same time, this will remove the cards from the stack, and thus ensure that cards are unique across the different players' hands. If you do not want this, use `random.sample` instead. This way, cards are unique within one hand, but not across hands, as they remain in the stack (in this case, the `shuffle` step is not needed, either):

```
hand = random.sample(cards, 12)
```

Comment: so random.shuffle() makes unique permutation of cards ?

Comment: @ShojibMahabub Depends on what you mean with "unique permutation". `random.shuffle` will shuffle the list, i.e. replace it with a random permutation of itself (in-place). If there are duplicate elements in the list to begin with, there will be duplicate elements in the permutation, and calling `random.shuffle` again does not guarantee a different permutation. As I said, just like shuffling a real deck of cards.

Answer (score 0):

What i would recommend is using `random.sample(population, k)` this will return a unique `k` items from the list `population`.

However for this you first need to make all the cards and then have all the cards in the list population.

Another solution would be to add a list `chosen_cards` and implement an equals funcion and do a check in the `chosen_cards` before you add the new random card to the `chosen_cards`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
cards = [(v, m) for (v, m) in zip(values * 4, marks * 13)]
random.sample(cards, 12)
# RESULT
[('K', 'diamond'),
 ('K', 'spade'),
 ('3', 'spade'),
 ('6', 'hearts'),
 ('10', 'spade'),
 ('9', 'hearts'),
 ('3', 'club'),
 ('8', 'hearts'),
 ('Q', 'spade'),
 ('Q', 'hearts'),
 ('6', 'club'),
 ('J', 'diamond')]
```